# No module names 'notifications.signals'; 'notifications' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x, django, notifications, celery

Hello I have a problem with a Django project. When I ran in Pycharm the celery I got this error :

`No module named 'notifications.signals'; 'notifications' is not a package`

Althought when I type in Python Console this :

`from notifications.signals import notify`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much

Comment: have u installed notifications?

Comment: I installed, django-notifications and django-notification but it does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

If you configure PyCharm to use the same environment that you used when you executed successfully the import statement, then it will all work as expected.